# "IN" expression in SQL SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I´ve got this expression here:

```
WHERE ProductName in ('%Comfort%','%Super%', '%Normal%','%PC%')
```

BUt it not work. The Table shows me "NaN" Values and Error.

Then I´ve tried it with this expression:

```
WHERE ProductName like '%Comfort%' AND ProductName like '%Super%' AND ProductName like '%Normal%' AND ProductName like '%PC%'
```

This was not working, too.

If I only use this expression

```
 WHERE ProductName like '%Comfort%'
```

Then it appears me what I want but I miss the other Products in my table.

Comment: Change the `AND` or `OR` in the second query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your second query was almost ok, since column  IN(x,y,z) is equals to

```
column = x or column = y or tcolumn = z
```

And not

```
column = x and column = y and tcolumn = z
```

The only problem there is you need to replace the 'AND' with an 'OR' like this:

```
WHERE ProductName like '%Comfort%' or ProductName like '%Super%' or ProductName like '%Normal%' or ProductName like '%PC%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use wildcards (`%`) in the `IN` clause.  The second where is saying `ProductName` that has "Super" And "Normal" And "PC" in it, so a product name "Normal Super PC" would be returned but not those that do not have all three in the name.

You need to change the `AND` to `OR`